# Same screen in different stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Assume that i have 3 stack navigator (with a bottom tab as base). And those 3 stack navigator do share a same screen that is navigatable.

Is it OK to share the same label and screen in all 3 stack navigator as follow? Or should i create 3 separate lable and screen Profile1, Profile2, Profile3? What is the general practice?

Also, is there any "gotcha" or weird behaviour if i share the same screen in different stack?

Note: I am using react-navigation `4.0.10`

```
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack1: Home1,
    Profile: Profile
  }
);

const Stack2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack2: Home2,
    Profile: Profile
  }
);


const Stack3 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack3: Home3,
    Profile: Profile
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Bottom1: Stack1,
    Bottom2: Stack2,
    Bottom3: Stack3
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
const Stack1 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack1: Home1,
    Profile1: Profile
  }
);

const Stack2 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack2: Home2,
    Profile2: Profile
  }
);


const Stack3 = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Stack3: Home3,
    Profile3: Profile
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Bottom1: Stack1,
    Bottom2: Stack2,
    Bottom3: Stack3
  }
```